# Azure deployment with eclipse result in error importing subscriptions from publish settings file

Tags: eclipse, azure, azure-deployment

My azure deployment from eclipse was working perfect. Untill i re-imported the PUBLISH-SETTINGS file with eclipse. Since then i'm receiving the following error:

> Exception:org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: package.xml:158:
>   com.microsoft.tooling.msservices.helpers.azure.AzureCmdException:
>   Error importing subscriptions from publish settings file

```
pluginId            org.eclipse.ant.launching
pluginVersion       1.1.101.v20160203-1242
code                0
severity            4
message             Ant Build Failed
fingerprint         2101170b882777b0017f6e1a72eceb81

Exception:org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: package.xml:158: com.microsoft.tooling.msservices.helpers.azure.AzureCmdException: Error importing subscriptions from publish settings file
     at org.eclipse.ant.core.AntRunner.handleInvocationTargetException(AntRunner.java:448)
     at org.eclipse.ant.core.AntRunner.run(AntRunner.java:380)
     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.launchConfigurations.AntLaunchDelegate.runInSameVM(AntLaunchDelegate.java:290)
     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.launchConfigurations.AntLaunchDelegate.launch(AntLaunchDelegate.java:249)
     at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:885)
     at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:739)
     at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:731)
     at org.eclipse.core.externaltools.internal.model.ExternalToolBuilder.launchBuild(ExternalToolBuilder.java:183)
     at org.eclipse.core.externaltools.internal.model.ExternalToolBuilder.doBuildBasedOnScope(ExternalToolBuilder.java:171)
     at org.eclipse.core.externaltools.internal.model.ExternalToolBuilder.build(ExternalToolBuilder.java:90)
     at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:734)
     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
     at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:205)
     at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:245)
     at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:300)
     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
     at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:303)
     at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:262)
     at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:402)
     at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project$1.run(Project.java:556)
     at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2241)
     at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.internalBuild(Project.java:534)
     at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.build(Project.java:111)
     at HIDDEN.HIDDEN(HIDDEN:-1)
     at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException: com.microsoft.tooling.msservices.helpers.azure.AzureCmdException: Error importing subscriptions from publish settings file
     at HIDDEN.HIDDEN(HIDDEN:-1)
     at HIDDEN.HIDDEN(HIDDEN:-1)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor75.invoke(null:-1)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(null:-1)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(null:-1)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Parallel$TaskRunnable.run(Parallel.java:454)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(null:-1)
Caused by: HIDDEN: Error importing subscriptions from publish settings file
     at HIDDEN.HIDDEN(HIDDEN:-1)
     at HIDDEN.HIDDEN(HIDDEN:-1)
     at HIDDEN.HIDDEN(HIDDEN:-1)
     at HIDDEN.HIDDEN(HIDDEN:-1)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor75.invoke(null:-1)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(null:-1)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(null:-1)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Parallel$TaskRunnable.run(Parallel.java:454)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(null:-1)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Service or property not registered:  com.microsoft.windowsazure.management.ManagementClient interface com.microsoft.windowsazure.management.ManagementClient
     at HIDDEN.HIDDEN(HIDDEN:-1)
     at HIDDEN.HIDDEN(HIDDEN:-1)
     at HIDDEN.HIDDEN(HIDDEN:-1)
     at HIDDEN.HIDDEN(HIDDEN:-1)
     at HIDDEN.HIDDEN(HIDDEN:-1)
     at HIDDEN.HIDDEN(HIDDEN:-1)
     at HIDDEN.HIDDEN(HIDDEN:-1)
     at HIDDEN.HIDDEN(HIDDEN:-1)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor75.invoke(null:-1)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(null:-1)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(null:-1)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Parallel$TaskRunnable.run(Parallel.java:454)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(null:-1)
```

I already tried the following:

1. retry importing the PUBLISH-SETTINGS file
2. revert back my azure project
3. start a clean azure deployment project
4. reinstall azure plugin in eclipse
5. removed the .m2 .p2 and .eclipse folder in c:\users\\
6. Install a new eclipse version (mars.2) and install azure with the eclipse market

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i solved it.

I found an extra option in Eclipse were i saw the button sign in. When i signed in the problem disappeared. To open this menu right click on your azure deployment project > properties > azure > subscriptions.

[image]

Comment: ran into this same issue. much appreciated advice.